# HTML Menu With Two Submenu

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu in html with a submenu opened with the hover of the element. The code for this menu is:

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href="" id="A3" style="width: 190px;" class="usernav">Tab Amministrativo <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul>
      <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/example1.aspx">example1</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/example2.aspx">example2</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/example3.aspx">example3</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

And this is the CSS associated:

```
    #cssmenu {
         line-height: 15px;
         text-align: left;
     }
    #cssmenu > ul {
        width: auto;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
        display: none;
        /* Hide for large screens */

    }
    #cssmenu > ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.right {
        float: right;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
        position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
        display: none;
        width: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
        background-image: url('images/caret.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 90% -95%;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
    #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
        background: #0a3f75 url('images/caret.png') no-repeat;
        background-position: 90% 195%;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #0a3f75;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul li a.active,
    #cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
        background: #0a3f75;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Now i need to add to this code another submenu that must be visible at the right or at the bottom of a specific value. For example i need to show a solution like this:

```
   <li class='has-sub'><a href="" id="A3" style="width: 190px;" class="usernav">Tab Amministrativo <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul>
          <li>example1
             <ul>
                <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/exampleSub1.aspx">exampleSub1</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/example2.aspx">example2</a></li>
          <li><a class="navbar-text" href="/Admin/Pages/example3.aspx">example3</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tyrj5xnu/1/ I want that 'Fatture Esterne' has subtab 'Crea Fatture' and 'Fat2'

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle, it's easier for anyone to help you with your issue

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
You can add this on your CSS

```
#cssmenu >ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub-lateral ul{
  display:none;
}
#cssmenu >ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub-lateral a:hover + ul {
  display:block;
  margin-left:250px;

}
```

I don't understad if it is what you need. But if put a `margin-left` (because you have a position absolute) you can see the `<ul>`

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. Can you edit my fiddle?